# Exception occurred calling method NotesAgent.runWithDocumentContext(lotus.domino.local.Document) null

Tags: xpages

I am working working with XPages from quite a long time and have always ignored this error but would like to understand the reason (and/or solution if possible).

So, my XPage agent when called from my web works perfectly fine. However, adding a JAVA script library to the agent would throw the error mentioned in my question title. I have seen this error many times and the obvious reason I am aware is the document being null but in this case I am sure document is not null (since, it runs without the additional script). Please find below the code for each of it.

```
// Javascript: default.js
var uId = myList.get(0); // this contains the document unique id
var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(uId);
var agentName = "groupRobot" ;
var agent:NotesAgent = database.getAgent(agentName);
if (agent != null)
{
if(doc == null){
// do nothing
}else{
agent.runWithDocumentContext(doc);
}
}
else {
getComponent("warningmessageBox").setValue("Failed to run the agent");
}


// Agent : groupRobot

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
Session session;
public void NotesMain() {
session = getSession();
//       ExtractGroup extract_group = new ExtractGroup();
//        extract_group.setSession(session);
//        boolean populatePersons = extract_group.start(); // calling the attached script library to replace group by persons
if(true){
System.out.println("Script finished sucessfully");
}
} // End of Notes Main
} // End of Class

// JAVA SCRIPT LIBRARY : extract_group

public class ExtractGroup {
Session session;
Vector<String> users= new Vector<String>();
Vector<String> groups= new Vector<String>();

public void setSession(Session session) {
this.session = session;
}
public boolean start() {
return true; // removed original code for being more clear
}
} // End of Class
```

I am not able to understand the reason for this. Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S. I have allowed restricted operations with administrator rights for the agent and also "Run as web user" option is selected

Edit 1: Based on the suggestion Knut Herrmann, I tried producing the same libraries and files on a new database and turns out that it works. Well, now the problem is the same thing ain't working my production database and I am not able to reproduce the error on the new database. Any suggestions in producing this error on new database and or removing this error from old database would be great. Thanks..!

---

Comment: Looks like your doc variable is null. Without the source where it came from and what you did to it, it is anybody's guess

Comment: No, it is not null..As I mentioned in my question, it works well without the Java script library. .

Comment: still you leave the audience to guess: look it works, but when I add something it stops working, but I neither tell where the document came from, nor what is inside the library that breaks my code. ROFL

Comment: I am sorry, if it was not clear. I will add the library in few minutes to make it even more clear.

Comment: Please check the improved question. Sorry, if it wasn't clear..!.. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps the `session` is null in the Java Library.

Comment: @Lauri: It is not even reaching there. It throws the exception before the agent being called. The wierd thing is that I am not even using the Java script library. I have just imported it.

Comment: Created a test app. Your example code works fine for me.

Comment: Yea, let me try it again. I have not exactly tried the very same example. I have more code inside the agent(Just removed it over here). But, I will create a fresh agent to find the source of error. Thanks :)

Comment: You could add java try...catch blocks with `exception.printStackTrace()` in both your agent and library. That way, you will get the exact line of code that causes the error (if the cause is in Java instead of SSJS). One thing to watch out is code in initialization block (e.g. new Vector())

Answer (score 1):

Set "Run as Web User" in agents security tab.

Look [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_and_Calling_Agents_Using_an_In-Memory_Document) for more information.

Comment: Forgot to mention, have already done that. :). As I mentioned in my question, it works fine without the JAVA script.

Comment: Hmm, without "Run as Web User" option I got exactly the same error message like you :-)

Comment: Yea, that is true, without that option being selected we get this error. However, this is something else I guess. Did you try adding an external "JAVA SCRIPT"("NOT JAVASCRIPT")?

Comment: Yes, exactly your example.

Comment: Yea, let me try it again. I have not exactly tried the very same example. I have more code inside the agent. But, I will create a fresh agent to find the source of error. Thanks :)

Comment: Still get the same error. I have created a new agent and just imported the java script library and it throws the error.

Comment: Try it with a new empty database... I am on version 8.5.3 right now. You too?

Comment: Yup, on the same version..let me test with a new database ( in few hours, just out of office) and post you back.. thank you for your reply :)

Comment: Confusing. You can import Java classes or jar files. There is nothing like a Java script. Java compiles. So something's wrong in the class or the compiler settings.

Comment: BTW: are you sure that it is good to use an agent in this case? It does only make sense if you use the agent from classic Notes client too. Otherwise it is much more efficient to execute the Java code from XPages SSJS direct. The agent has it's own complete JVM environment and it pretty much separated from XPages world.

Comment: @stwissel: confusing? ... it is the old Java world in Notes Domino. A way to share Java classes between Java agents is to create ScriptLibraries of type "Java" and import them into the agent as "Script Library". They show up then in folder "Lib".

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply..Well, I tried it on a new database and it works well, however, I am not able to reproduce the error on the new database. Any idea, what could be wrong here?

Comment: @previous comment: Yea, kind of need to run an agent, since it has options to run with the document context which I don't believe we have with the JAVA script library. Also, I am not aware how exactly the "JAVA" script library could be used independently. Couled there be a better approach to this?

Comment: You'd put your Java classes into `Code / Java`. You can call a Java class from SSJS this way: `var extract_group = new com.company.ExtractGroup(); extract_group.setSession(session); ...` The current document you could pass as a argument.

Comment: Yea, that's one approach. My problem is that I have a scheduled agent which runs say ever night and I would like to run the very same agent via web which is causing the problem. (as of now I have 2 agents, scheduled agent(with JAVA script) and normal agent(without JAVA script). I was planning to merge it to one but I don't see it possible now. Anyways thanks a ton. I will look into it.>!

Comment: You have a working version (new database) and faulty version (production database) now. You can put design element by design element from production database into new database to look when it starts to crash. Or, delete peace by peace from a copy of your production database and look when it will work. You have the best tools right now to find out what the cause if the issue is :-)

Answer (score 0):

What is your Java source level? You have parameter  in your `new Vector()` which is not available in Domino Java Library by default. Check both project and editor levels:

*File --> Preferences --> Java --> Compiler --> Compiler compliance level*

*(2nd button click) --> Project properties --> Java compiler --> JDK compliance*

This could cause the class initialization to fail before the constructor is ran.

Comment: I don't think so it has anything to do with java compliance level, since even after removing that part it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Java source files must match the class they contain. Your question suggests the file you import is extract_group while your class is ExtractGroup 
You however should get a warning or error at compile time.

Comment: Yes, I think I missed that. But there is no compile time error. Let me verify it as soon as I am in office. Thanks a lot.